FastAPI Users making subscriptions model
Got exception:
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Relationship User.followings could not determine any unambiguous local/remote column pairs based on join condition and remote_side arguments. Consider using the remote() annotation to accurately mark those elements of the join condition that are on the remote side of the relationship.

I tried all the ways to indicate connections in models. I don't know what to do(
My User model
class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable[int], Base):
    ...
    followings = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=Subscription,
        primaryjoin=(id == Subscription.c.follower_id),  # local side сторона
        secondaryjoin=(id == Subscription.c.author_id),   # remote side 
        back_populates='followers',
        remote_side=Subscription.c.author_id,
        viewonly=True
    )

    followers = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=Subscription,
        primaryjoin=(id == Subscription.c.author_id),     # local side
        secondaryjoin=(id == Subscription.c.follower_id),  # remote side
        back_populates='followings',
        remote_side=Subscription.c.follower_id,
        viewonly = True
    )

My Subscription Table
Subscription = Table(
    'followers',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('follower_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

In my opinion, the main problem in this code was the id
My models are inherited from the Base model, in which the Id was specified
class PreBase:

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)


Base = declarative_base(cls=PreBase)

but as I understand it, this method is not suitable for creating the model connection I need
the article that helped me: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/join_conditions.html#self-referential-many-to-many-relationship
Final code:
followers = Table(
    'followers',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    Column('follower_id', Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True)
)

class User(SQLAlchemyBaseUserTable[int], Base):
    id = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    ...
    followings: Mapped[List['User']] = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=id == followers.c.follower_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == followers.c.author_id,
        back_populates='followers',
    )

    followers: Mapped[List['User']] = relationship(
        'User',
        secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=id == followers.c.author_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == followers.c.follower_id,
        back_populates='followings',
    )

